# Find and Delete out of range data from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Latitude and Longitude dataset (pandas dataframe). I tried to find minimum and maximum values of latitude and longitude to get a bounding box and export the image of the area from Open Street Map. The results is showing out of range data and I want to find and remove all of out of range data from my dataset. Not sure what is the best way of doing this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use np.where. For e.g. you want to filter out longitude & latitude of certain range, you can use this in way

```
np.where((df['longitude']>=100) & (df['latitude']<=100) | (df['longitude']<=100) & (df['latitude']>=100)  )
```

Ofcourse you need to modify range/column name & equality logic based on the requirement.

More information will certainly help in answer question better.